# How do you declare a global set of an object which is used in the objects class?

Tags: c++

I have a class called `WaterJug`

In one of the `WaterJug` methods, I want to access a global `Set<WaterJug>`.

However, when I define the `Set<WaterJug>` before the `class WaterJug {}` I get an error `Use of undeclared identifier`.

When I define the `Set<WaterJug>` after the class, then I get `Use of undeclared identifier` when trying access the set in the class's methods.

Is there anyway around this?

```
set<WaterJug> jug;


class WaterJug {
public:
    int capA, capB, capC;
    int goalA, goalB, goalC;
    int currA, currB, currC;

   //tons of methods...

};
```

Comment: show the code you tried!!

Comment: Put `set<WaterJug> jug;` after the class definition, and don't do inline definition for methods which need to use `jug`